# Why Map function not works in nested stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Hi In the below code map function wont run but for each run

```
List<ValidationError> validationErrors = validationErrorResponse.getValidationErrors();
validationErrors.stream().forEach(validationError -> {
    System.out.println("Hello1"+validationError.getProperty());
    System.out.println("Hello1"+validationError.getErrors().toString());
    List<String> errors = validationError.getErrors();
            errors.stream().map(x-> ErrorCode.valueOf(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` is an intermediate operation on stream. So it will executed iff you add a terminal operation, like `collect` or `forEach` to it.

So something like:

```
errors.stream().map(x-> ErrorCode.valueOf(x)).forEach( x -> System.out.println(x) );
```

Comment: but it works if we are not using nested streams? like e.getValidationErrors().stream().map(x-> ErrorCode.valueOf(x));